# remove html extension on a website with no backend

Tags: .htaccess

I'm coding a simple one pager with no backend as the website won't have a database etc.
Thus the project consists of only 3 files: home.html, styles.css, script.js.
Everything seems to be working fine except for one thing: the address looks like this http://127.0.0.1:5500/home.html.

When I upload the website onto a hosting provider, I'd like the ULR to look like this: http://mywebsite.com/home or even http://mywebsite.com. (I haven't chosen a provider though).

The internet says that I need to create a .htaccess file and add a couple of lines of code to it to accomplish my goal but as far a I understand the .htaccess file is a server-side file. How can I use it and make it do the trick if I have no backend?

Right now I don't really think it's possible to remove the html extension in my situation and to do so I do need some kind of backend coded.

But anyway could you please confirm whether I understand the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion of terms here, I think. In a way your hosting provider is a backend you are using. A server side system that serves the three files. It is a http server, that is the component that interprets such a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). So all components are present, it should be possible to achieve what you ask.

Maybe you could rename the file `home.html` to `index.html`? Then *most likely* things will work out of the box due to the typical default settings hosting providers chose. Have a try.

If that does *not* work, then indeed you would have to add a rewriting rule. Something like that should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.html [END]
```

Obviously `index.html` or `home.html`, depending on how you finally name that file, `index.html` is simply the *typical* name.

That should allow to load the page via a URL like `https://example.com/`, so without an additional path. The path (the file name) is added by the internal rewriting when the request is processed by the http server.

You might also want to add an external redirection, so that requests to `https://example.com/index.html` get redirected to just `https://example.com/`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?index\.html` / [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.html [END]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand how it works. The truth is I've never deployed a project before, so I had a feeling the hosting provider would provide the backend part to me with its default settings in .htaccess etc but I wasn't really sure. In this case, I don't have to worry too much about anything as long as the hosting provider is a good one.

Comment: Since you implemented your page on a local system I assume you operate a web environment yourself, so at least a http server. That is what the hosting provider offers too, though usually additional things as well, like database server and the like. However the http server follows exactly the same logic as your local one. No magic involved ...